# Mejorar imagen para extracción OCR con pytesseracrt

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

Hola tengo la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A la cual le quiero aplicar la técnica OCR para extraer su la fecha: 
02-01-2017

Cuando trato de hacerlo con `tesseract` :

```
ptesseract.image_to_string(imageforOCR, lang = "spa", config='-c    
tessedit_char_whitelist=-/0123456789')
```

El resultado no es el mejor ya que algunos numero los toma mal debido a la resolución de la imagen.

El resultado es:
02-617-2517, si le aplico un `edge detection` con `opencv` para ver su contorno obtengo lo siguiente: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y concluyo que sus bordes son muy irregulares y por lo tanto que pueden estar confundiendo el algoritmo de la extracción, ¿como puedo definir mejor los números, la imagen  o que me recomiendan hacerle a la imagen para lograr un buen resultado de extracción, esta imagen es solo un ejemplo de muchas que tengo que extraer con las mismas características de resolución que les dejo a continuación:

1. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Comentarios: 1) Salvo 16/02/2017, el resto las he interpretado perfecto con la herramienta `capture2text` (que usa tesseract), lo que sí resulta necesario recortar perfectamente el area del texto. 2) La resolución es crítica para cualquier OCR, si es demasiado baja no hay mucho que se pueda hacer 3) Te sugiero algunas técnicas para mejorar un poco la imagen y que tienes en opencv: "Blur", termina "suavizando" la imagen, a veces funciona, "Dilate", "engrosa" los patrones, pero puede empastar, "Erode", si  al revés la imagen está empastada.

Comment: 4) Fundamental además es quitar la "suciedad", o sea los puntos o patrones innecesarios, tienes una rutina `connectedComponentsWithStats` que te permite establecer un minímo de pixels conectados para determinar que es un patrón válido y que no lo es. 5) En tus imágenes veo que tienes lineas horizontales o verticales, que sería bueno detectar y quitar.

Answer (score 1):

te recomiendo realizar un preprocesamiento antes de aplicar OCR, me ha funcionado mucho las transformaciones morfológicas. La librería de OPENCV te permite con dos líneas de código aplicar un concepto llamado sal y pimienta que se enfoca en eliminar ruido.
Esto ayuda mucho también cuando escaneas la imagen y se generan puntos o se pierde parte de las siluetas de las palabras.

[image: Closing]

[image: Opening]

Recuerda que puedes definir el tamaño de los puntos que deseas quitar o rellenar con np.ones((15, 15)

```
import cv2
path = 'menu.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(path )
kernel = np.ones((15, 15), np.uint8)
kernel2 = np.ones((10, 10), np.uint8)
img = cv2.morphologyEx(img , cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
img = cv2.morphologyEx(img , cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel2)
```

Answer (score 0):

aqui tienes un ejemplo funciona para mi:

```
from PIL import Image
from pytesser import *

image_file = 'menu.jpg'
im = Image.open(image_file)
text = image_to_string(im)
text = image_file_to_string(image_file)
text = image_file_to_string(image_file, graceful_errors=True)
print "=====RESULTADO=======\n"
print text
```

Comment: gracias pero no funciona para mi. :(

Comment: ¿Como resolvería la pregunta del OP este código de ejemplo?, sería conveniente agregar esa información. Revisar [answer].